# Actionscript 3 FileReference load/save strings

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flex3, flash-cs5

I am using file reference to prompt the user to save the file to a directory of their choice. The file extension for saving is a text-file, it has the string "Hello!" It does manage to save the file.

I am having trouble loading it and importing the string to stage so that the stage reads the instruction on the FileReference .txt file and goes to the page. For example, the string "Hello" should go to page = "Hello";

Please help? If someone can provide an example on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What are you targeting? Web (swf), Air app (iOS, Android)?

Comment: You can't load local files in a SWF for security reasons. You have to serve your files from a http web server (host them somewhere).

Comment: Yes, I am hosting them on a server. It opens up a dialogue box which saves the users preferences of current page on to their hard-disk. Later they load it (the preference text file) and it reads (SWF) the strings sending them to that page in the (SWF).

Comment: So... you want the user to select the saved file from their computer and make your app display the page mentioned in the file?

Comment: Yes, exactly this :)

Comment: Are you getting any IO errors? Follow this tutorial and you should get it running in no time: https://permadi.com/2010/06/flash-as3-using-filereference-to-load-files-example-for-flash-cs4-and-above/

Comment: Oh, also the file is an .SWF File I am targeting web, not iOS or Android only Computer Operating Systems. I tested it and save the text file, I loaded the file but I need Flash to read the data in the file convert them to strings and evaluate the string to the page it should send the user to. I already read it, I'm having trouble applying the loaded data to the swf.

Comment: See the tutorial above .... `data.toString();` will be the string in your file; in the onFileLoaded event listener callback.

Comment: Okay, I think I got the idea. Thanks!